# Which bios should I use for P877-V PRO/THUNDERBOLT mobo?

Tags: installation

First off, I'm a total noob with linux. I've done some google searches trying to find how to go about laying the groundwork for a fresh install of linux, using the components listed below, with no luck.  Before I get to learning how to use linux, I figure I need to get it running first.

These are the specs of my brand new, budget, DIY rig:

- Motherboard: ASUS P8Z77-V PRO/THUNDERBOLT
- CPU: i5-3570K
- GPU: ASUS HD7850-DC2-2GD5-V2 Radeon HD
- RAM: G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 16GB(2x8GB) DDR3 1600
- HDD: Velociraptor WD5000HHTZ 500GB (nothing installed whatsoever)
- Monitor: BenQ 24" GL2450HM
- Disk Drive: LG WH14NS40K

I've heard there have been problems with the default bios on this mobo, problems fixed with a recent bios update.  However, going to the [bios download page for the mobo](http://usa.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z77V_PROTHUNDERBOLT/#download) in search of a newer bios, there're no versions for linux, despite the fact I've read (dated) posts about others getting linux to run on this mobo.

Again, I'm just trying to get all the proper bios updates and drivers lined up before even turning on the system and proceeding with an install of ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.

Any links or info anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading this, and apologies if this same question's been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

System BIOS is not OS specific.

You can update if you want, but I would install Ubuntu first, and then see if its needed. Because normally, if everything works OK, then I wouldn't recommend a BIOS update, unless its needed.  So go ahead and install Ubuntu, and then see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, Mitch.  

I guess I was just kinda worried having seen some have had problems using the default bios that not doing anything might fry something.  I'll give'er a go and update this post.

Best regards!